# Accessing nested properties

Tags: powershell, object, properties

Would it be possible to access a nested property by using a variable name?

Some code to clarify:

```
$MyObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = 'Object name'
    Input = @{
        Error = @{
            Terminating = @(
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Type = 'Error.Terminating'
                    Name = 'MissingParameter'
                    Description = $null
                    Value = @($null)
                }
            )
            NonTerminating = @(
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Type = 'Error.NonTerminating'
                    Name = 'FileNotMoved'
                    Description = $null
                    Value = @($null)
                }
            )
        }
        Warning = @(
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Type = 'Warning'
                Name = 'ADObjectConflict'
                Description = $null
                Value = @($null)
            }
        )
    }
}
# Correct result    
$MyObject.Input.Error.Terminating

# Incorrect result    
$string = 'Error.Terminating'
$MyObject.Input.$string

# Incorrect result        
$MyObject.Input.($MyObject.Input.Error.Terminating[0].Type)
```

The last two statements don't return the object in question. It would be great if they could be addressed by using a variable.

Comment: `Error` and `Terminating` are two different objects.  You would need to do something like `$Err,$Term = 'Error','Terminating'`

Comment: True, but I am trying to extract their data which can easily be done by static typing `$MyObject.prop1.prop2.prop3..`. The only thing I'm interested in, is knowing if `prop2` and `prop3` can be replaced with a variable.

Comment: They *can* by using `Invoke-Expression`, I think.  But [just know it's a terrible practice in most use-cases](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). `Invoke-Expression -Command '$MyObject.Input.$string'`

Comment: ``Invoke-Expression  "`$MyObject.Input.$string"`` (use double quotes and a backtick before the first $)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 you are correct, it seems that it's not best practice. Reverting to another way of handling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @TheIncorregible pointed out, `Error and Terminating are two different objects`. You can do a workaround like this one, in order to get the desired result:

```
# Correct result    
$property1 = 'Error'
$property2 = 'Terminating'

$MyObject.Input.($property1).($property2)
```

This way, we got the following output:

```
Type              Name             Description Value  
----              ----             ----------- -----  
Error.Terminating MissingParameter             {$null}
```